# Booting Ubuntu from Sata USB not working. Will it work if installed in laptop?

Tags: boot, sata

I have a 2016 ASUS X556UA laptop. It has a windows SSD drive installed. I connected a Ubuntu SSD via a SATA to USB drive. (It boots using this method on an even older laptop.)
Here is the BIOS boot screen.  It does not seem to recognise the drive.  I can disassemble the laptop and install the Ubuntu drive but I would like to know if this is likely to make any difference because I prefer to find an external solution.

Thank you[image]

Comment: Most distro installer will install UEFI bootloader / boot manager in the way that the EFI executable is registered to the UEFI firmware. Therefore, you'll need to either register it to the new computer (manually with `efibootmgr`, or reinstall the bootloader / boot manager), or copy the executable to the fallback path (`[EFI partition]/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi`) which the UEFI firmware will discover automatically.

Comment: Also try to update your BIOS.